# How to document CPU cycles, RAM, etc. after logging and showing of zsh?

Tags: debian, shell, terminal, zsh

I am using the [Debian testing distribution](https://www.debian.org/devel/testing).

Since a few weeks ago I have been experiencing quite a bit of time lag when opening zsh - on the order of 3-5 minutes. I have no idea if it's something in login, mate, some other application or if it's due to zsh itself.

I am looking for something like Mozilla's Developer Tools [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) where it shows a waterfall where the time for the connection to be sent/arrived at the browser/client-side is displayed for each TCP connection.

Would it require hacking/cobbling together a script to know what interactions are happening?

Comment: more typical is `zsh -x` and see where ZSH is being slow

Comment: what does 'zsh -x' do. It seems it makes a dump of something but not sure how to wade through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start `zsh` as:

```
PS4='+[%D{%T.%.}] %N:%i> ' zsh -x
```

(add `-l` to simulate a login shell) that will tell you what the shell is doing with millisecond time stamps.

`-x` turns the `xtrace` option like in all Bourne-like shells. `PS4` adjusts the prompt string for those traces.

If the delay is not about the commands in zsh startup files, then you could also run your terminal emulator under `strace` to see where the time is spent:

```
 strace -fttT -o strace.log xterm
```

(avoid `gnome-terminal` for that as it connects to *server* process to start the session and that's that process you'd need to `strace`).